# Could not match kind: KindsDoNotUnify error

Tags: purescript

This is a strange error I encountered while in practice, the thing is that there is a data type, that has an alias (defined in another module) and deriving `newtype` instance for the type the uses this alias type leads to the compiler error.

So, I tried to narrow it down the case, it requires two small modules to be reproduced:

Module A, which uses `TAlias` from `Module B` to declare `newtype` and derive `Newtype` instance:

```
module A where


import B (TAlias)
import Data.Newtype (class Newtype)

data M a = M a

-- define a type that uses alas type
newtype NewA a = NewA (TAlias (M a))


derive instance Newtype (NewA a) _
```

`Module B`, where `T` and `TAlias` are defined

```
module B where


data T :: forall m. m -> Type
data T msg = E


type TAlias :: forall k. k -> Type
type TAlias msg = 
  T msg --  here is is the error
```

In the last line of the `module B` the compiler (Purescript 0.14.4) gives an error:

```
 Could not match kind

    Type

  with kind

    k


while checking that type M a
  has kind k
while inferring the kind of T @k (M a)
while inferring the kind of Newtype (NewA a) (T @k (M a))
in type class instance

  Data.Newtype.Newtype (NewA a)
                       (T @k (M a))
PureScript(KindsDoNotUnify)
```

So I wonder what is the reason for the error? How it can be fixed to allow deriving Newtype in such a case.

Comment: This is definitely a bug. A smaller repro would be `NewA (TAlias Int)`, you don't need `M a` for this, and you don't need the `derive Newtype` either, it fails just at the `newtype` declaration. `NewA (T Int)` works, but `NewA (TAlias Int)` doesn't, but it starts working if you replace the `TAlias`'s kind signature with `Type -> Type`. So the problem is that, when the compiler expands `TAlias`, it's treating the variable `k` as rigid, and instantiates  variable `m` with it. But it only works when `TAlias` is in a different module. Definitely a bug. I recommend filing an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Will raise the issue.